# Report on Incoming Emails discarded by SharePoint job?

Tags: sharepoint-server, incoming-email, email-enabled-library

Is there a way to get report on all emails that SharePoint discarded while processing them from drop Folder? Emails with multiple attachments (same name) are automatically getting discarded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB method to directly get the report for getting discarded incoming emails in SharePoint.

As a workaround, you can check the ULS log to filter with the related error. ULS is located on:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

Comment: Thanks for responding but I can't go through ULS logs for the entire day to find which are the missing emails. Also ULS just provides the eml filename and reason but nothing else even if you turn on Verbose.